# That code will be leak memory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Today I saw some code that I think will leak memory:

```
/* realloc example: rememb-o-matic */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* realloc, free, exit, NULL */

int main ()
{
  int input,n;
  int count = 0;
  int* numbers = NULL;
  int* more_numbers = NULL;

  do {
     printf ("Enter an integer value (0 to end): ");
     scanf ("%d", &input);
     count++;

     more_numbers = (int*) realloc (numbers, count * sizeof(int));

     if (more_numbers!=NULL) {
       numbers=more_numbers;
       numbers[count-1]=input;
     }
     else {
       free (numbers);
       puts ("Error (re)allocating memory");
       exit (1);
     }
  } while (input!=0);

  printf ("Numbers entered: ");
  for (n=0;n<count;n++) printf ("%d ",numbers[n]);
  free (numbers);

  return 0;
}
```

I think the program fails to free all of the memory referenced by pointer `numbers` before assigning a new value to that pointer. The program frees the the memory that `numbers` points to only during the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: You allocate storage for one array and free storage for one array.  Looks good to me except this is C code and not C++.

Comment: `realloc` does the right thing - if it allocates a new block, it frees the old one. In C++ you would use `std::vector `, which just works.

Comment: oh i'm sorry it is C. i understood, " it frees the old one" :) thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only answer to the question is "No".

Comment: Just so nobody is confused, this also looks like 100% C++.

Answer (score 2):

the following things are done by the realloc() function.

1. the prior contents of the allocated memory are copied to the new allocation
2. the prior allocation is passed to `free()`
3. the address of the new allocation is returned.

Note: the above only happens if the `realloc()` function is able to actually perform the new memory allocation.  If the new memory allocation fails, then `NULL` is returned.

So the posted code does not have a memory leak because the function: `realloc()` handles free'ing the old memory allocation.

Comment: Indeed, the code presented even demonstrates good handling of the case where `realloc()` fails, despite the fact that it is about to exit and thereby release all allocated memory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not cause a memory leak as already mentioned. Since it is a pure C code you can use a C implementation of a linked-list (if you don't want C++ STL structures). You will see also the capability of allocating/deallocating memory for one more integer during runtime!